# how to complete integer cast operator overload function signature here

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, typecasting-operator, typecast-operator

Can someone please help me out with this question? I am unable to understand how to perform type cast overload here since typcast is not supposed to receive any arguments so naturally any attempts at giving it one fail too.

Fill in the blank at LINE-3 to complete integer cast operator overload function signature.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class intString{
    int *arr;
    int n;
    public:
        intString(int k) : n(k){} //LINE-1
        int operator = (int n){ //LINE-2
            return arr[--n];
        }
        __________________(int &k){ //LINE-3
            int t;
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                cin >> t;
                this->arr[j] = t;
            }
            return *this;
        }
};
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    intString s(k);
    s = k;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << static_cast<int>(s) << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried

```
operator int()(int&k){
.
.
.
}
```

and

```
operator int(int&k){
.
.
.
}
```

However, that obviously didn't work. I am really at a loss at what to do here.

---

Edit:
Here is the question:
Consider the following program with the following instructions.

- Fill in the blank at LINE-1 to complete constructor definition.
- Fill in the blank at LINE-2 to complete assignment operator overload function signature.
- Fill in the blank at LINE-3 to complete integer cast operator overload function signature.

Here is the code block unedited:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class intString{
    int *arr;
    int n;
    public:
        intString(int k) : ______________________{} //LINE-1
        _______________{ //LINE-2
            return arr[--n];
        }
        __________________(int &k){ //LINE-3
            int t;
            for(int j = 0; j < k; j++){
                cin >> t;
                this->arr[j] = t;
            }
            return *this;
        }
};
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    intString s(k);
    s = k;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << static_cast<int>(s) << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the parameter? Who gave you the task and what is the exact wording?

Comment: `return *this;` makes no sense in `operator int` either. `operator int` returns an `int` and `return *this` would require a conversion to `int` but thats what `operator int` should do. You must have misunderstood something

Comment: `operator=` looks rather messed up too. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: and `arr` is an uninitialized pointer. There are sooo many problems with this code. Rather than filling the `__________________` blank you should place it in the trash and start from scratch

Comment: Takes an `int&` and returns this object, possibly by reference. Hmm, some cursed assignment operator?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  It's an assignment these are the exact words of the assignment.

Consider the following program with the following instructions.

• Fill in the blank at LINE-1 to complete constructor definition.
• Fill in the blank at LINE-2 to complete assignment operator overload function signature.
• Fill in the blank at LINE-3 to complete integer cast operator overload function signature.

Comment: frankly it looks like the assignment is crap or you messed up the first two parts too much or both. In the code you posted there is no way to fill the blank that will not result in totally broken code. If you need help with the task you should include the text of the task in the quesiton and also show the code that comes with the task (seperate from the code you already added).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Here is the code unedited.
`#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class intString{
    int *arr;
    int n;
    public:
        intString(int k) : ______________________{} //LINE-1
        _______________{ //LINE-2
            return arr[--n];
        }
        __________________(int &k){ //LINE-3`

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75758873/edit) the question to add missing information. Though, the parts I see in the comments look really weird. I am getting more and more convinced that the assignment is not worth its price. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry for constantly adding and removing the comment. I am new and this is my first post, so I was kinda figuring out how to post a code block in comments. Back to the initial convo. Well I would have loved to but I have paid for the course...

Comment: That's by far the worst abuse of `operator=` I've seen in the thirty or so years I've been C++-ing. But none of this makes any sense.

Comment: I am really curious to see the full code provided by the assignment (you cannot properly format code in comments, the code should be in the question). If it as bad as it looks from the incomplete part in your comment, imho its reason enough to ask back your money. This is not teaching you proper C++, rather the opposite

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It's an assignment from NPTEL. It's a government platform where various reputed institutes like IIT and their profs. come and teach in exchange for certificates. It's the assignment for this week and last 2 hours left until submission time ends.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have edited the question and added the unedited code block and the full question there.

Comment: The original assignment is equally puzzling. The only part that can be salvaged is LINE-1 - don't forget to initialize arr.

Comment: @molbdnilo I apologize, I am open to any suggestions you might have to improve myself. I am open to knowledge and learning proper etiquette of coding. Please let me know more.

Comment: Right, so they mixed up the hints for 2&3. LINE-2 is supposed to be cast-to-int and LINE-3 is assign-from-int. But the whole thing is really cursed and bad.

Comment: @teapot418 oh.... good spot. I was too much focused on all the other weirdness in the code that I didnt see the obvious confusion between 2 and 3 :)

Comment: Please find different source to learn C++. Clearly this question/test has many mistakes, which are harmful for the student. And problem is not only mixed up line numbers as pointed out in accepted answer. This looks like a problem written by someone who just read beginner/medium courses and didn't understood everything.

Comment: @MarekR I will certainly look for more. I am also open to any suggestions/references you might have for me to follow. I am not bound to just C++. If you have any suggestions be it in field of ML, AI, DA, Cloud, Compiler Design, etc, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the code below // LINE 3, it seems like the question mixed up what line LINE 2 and LINE 3 are supposed to do. The block returns
`*this`, which is an object of type `intString`, not an integer. Furthermore, user-defined type casts or type overloads like these don't allow a param to be passed to them, so k won't be defined in the scope of that method.

Moreover, a look at the driver code suggests that the assignment `s = k;` should take some user input that sets the values in `arr`, which can then be fetched by the loop below. At LINE 2, n shouldn't be passed as it's a data member of the class...

I think the question got flipped for LINE 2 and LINE 3.

So, to sum up LINE 1, LINE 2 and LINE 3 should probably be -

LINE-1:

> intString(int k) : n(k), arr(new int[k]) {

LINE-2:

> operator int() {

LINE-3:

> intString operator= (int &k) {

I've purposefully left the above spoiler tagged, in case you want to solve this yourself.

Comment: `&` is missing in one case!

Comment: Oh thanks, @MarekR. I didn't realise that initially.
LINE-3 should return a reference to `intString` instead of returning by value to conserve resources

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the conversion operator.

For example it can look the following way

```
operator const int & () const 
{
    return n;
}
```

or just

```
operator int () const
{
    return n;
}
```

These operators may be defined with specifier explicit

```
explicit operator const int & () const 
{
    return n;
}
```

or

```
explicit operator int () const
{
    return n;
}
```

Pay attention to that the data member `arr`

```
class intString{
    int *arr;
    //...
```

is not initialized. So your code can invoke undefined behavior.